# How do I get the values of the List<Map<Integer, String>>?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hello community have a query, is that I have a query that returns me the data in a `List <Map <Integer, String>>`

**Query HQL Hibernate:**

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public List<Map<Integer, String>> obtenerPermisosForm(int icodUsu, int icodRol) throws Exception {
    try {
        StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
        hql.append("select new Map(opc.id.icodMaeMenu as icodMaeMenu, ");
        hql.append("opc.videObj as videObj) ");
        hql.append("from Sgmaeopc opc ");
        hql.append("inner join opc.sgmaemenu men ");
        hql.append("inner join men.sgusurol usr ");
        hql.append("inner join usr.sgusuario us ");
        hql.append("inner join usr.sgrol rl ");
        hql.append("where opc.id.icodUsuario = :icodUsu ");
        hql.append("and opc.id.icodRol = :icodRol ");
        hql.append("and men.bactivo = :bactivo ");
        hql.append("and us.bactivo = :bactivo ");
        Query query = super.getSession().createQuery(hql.toString());
        query.setParameter("icodUsu", icodUsu);
        query.setParameter("icodRol", icodRol);
        query.setParameter("bactivo", Constantes.ESTADO_ACTIVO_TRUE);       
        return query.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception( getGenerarError(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(), 
                             Constantes.NIVEL_APP_DAO,
                             this.getClass().getName(),
                             e.getMessage()) );
    }
}
```

**And I try to capture controller data in this way.**

```
List<Map<Integer, String>> permisos = userService.obtenerPermisosForm(getCVariableSesion().getIcodUsu(),
                                                                     getCVariableSesion().getIcodRol());

for(Map<Integer, String> map : permisos) {
    System.out.println("===> "+map+" | "+map.get("videObj"));
}
```

**But the problem that I have is to capture the value of the integer code for the description of "icodMaeMenu"**

```
===> {videObj=menuItemMarcas001, icodMaeMenu=14} | menuItemMarcas001
===> {videObj=menuItemMarcas002, icodMaeMenu=14} | menuItemMarcas002
===> {videObj=menuItemMarcas003, icodMaeMenu=14} | menuItemMarcas003
===> {videObj=menuItemMarcas005, icodMaeMenu=14} | menuItemMarcas005
```

If I try to access the **map.get("icodMaeMenu")**, it generates an error that can **not cast an Integer to a String**, you should consult that do in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not storing entirely homogeneous objects into that map.  I'll give you that you're at least storing a `String` as a key, but the values could either be `String` or `Integer`.

You could change your `Map` to be `List<Map<String, Object>>`.  This has the distinct disadvantage of you not being able to accurately predict what exactly is in that mapping, and it forces you to cast based on what string you're working with.

Alternatively, you could ditch the map altogether and create some sort of wrapper object that encapsulates both of those objects neatly, and removes the need to do *any* casting at all.

I won't write the class since I don't know what the best name for it would be, but I can give you the fragment of HQL you'd require:

```
"select new Wrapper(opc.id.icodMaeMenu, opc.videObj)" +
// rest of append here...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change `List<Map<Integer, String>> permisos` to `List<Map<String, Object>> permisos`. It looks like the key of your maps is a String and the value can be either Integer or String.